# How can I load images later for the Ar Augmented Image Database?

Tags: android, c++, augmented-reality, arcore

I test it with a click listener. I load it, but no tracking of the newly loaded image. How can I do it?

```
void AugmentedImageApplication::onLoad() {
             ArAugmentedImageDatabase *ar_augmented_image_database = CreateAugmentedImageDatabase();
             ArConfig_setAugmentedImageDatabase(ar_session_, ar_config,                         ar_augmented_image_database);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a call (ArAugmentedImageDatabase_addImage) to actually add an image to your database before calling ArConfig_setAugmentedImageDatabase().

```
ArStatus ArAugmentedImageDatabase_addImage(
  const ArSession *session,
  ArAugmentedImageDatabase *augmented_image_database,
  const char *image_name,
  const uint8_t *image_grayscale_pixels,
  int32_t image_width_in_pixels,
  int32_t image_height_in_pixels,
  int32_t image_stride_in_pixels,
  int32_t *out_index
)
```

Docs on the method above: https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/augmented-image-database#group__augmented__image__database_1ga611cdc55ad8452e21de6ef8d41c381ea